# Blocking an SSDP Flood

Tags: networking

I've been hosting game-servers since a long time and I keep updating my iptables firewall time and again to block most attacks. One of my game-server port is being flooded with "SSDP" requests and my game-server replies to that with a "disconnect" packet.

Here is how the stream is established coming from Source Port 1900 while the destination is my game-server port,

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8099734/

I have the following iptables configuration that should have been blocking the outgoing "disconnect" packets but it's not working anymore and I have no idea why.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8099779/

I have temporarily blocked input from UDP source-port 1900 but that is not a good enough solution as my game-server is vulnerable to many other packets so the outgoing "disconnect" packet is something that has to be blocked.

I'm not sure if -m multiport match might be required to block this?

Comment: SSDP packets shouldn't even be happening unless your game server's not on its own network (i.e, you're doing this at home). SSDP is used almost exclusively by UPnP discovery.

Comment: It's not at home. It's actually a flood I'm getting with 100 different IP Addresses on my dedicated server. And that is how my game-server is replying to those packets. Maybe it's a new way to generate an application specific flood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that what you are receiving looks like a reply package, not a request.

So most likely this is an amplification type attack, where they send a small request to SSDP enabled devices on the net, but with your IP spoofed as originator. So when all these devices send their reply, you get 'em.

As an added side effect, your service has no idea what they are talking about and have no choice but to "disconnect" them (which the game server apparently does by sending the text disconnect).

I dont understand why you are targeting your reply to this. Id try going for the incoming package instead, with something like:

> iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 16000:29000 -m string --to 75 --algo
>   bm --string 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' -j DROP

Comment: I also thought of doing something like that but this is just a specific case. Sometimes my game-server also responds to various other type of packets with a "disconnect" packet. I want to block them all together. Why won't that work? @thelogix

Comment: Im just thinking that the "disconnect" message must be there for a reason and removing it may cause trouble in some scenarios. But thats just a guess ofcourse. I'll re-examine your iptables.. Hang on.

Comment: No your '-A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 16000:29000 -m string --algo bm --string "disconnect" -j DROP' should work. There nothing "accepting" the package ealier, so i dont know why it doesnt. My guess is that one of the conditions arent met. Like, the source port isnt within the range or table should be FORWARD instead. You can do 'iptables -L -n -v' and see how many packages that hit the rule, to maybe tell you whats happening.

Comment: The rule did work fine before but since the SSDP it stopped working. I've no idea why. The port is 20380 so it should be in range. Maybe I should reformat it to something like "-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --match multiport --sports 16000:29000 -m string --algo bm --string "disconnect" -j DROP"?

Comment: Sure try it. It cant hurt. I've also been thinking that it may be something like "recent" or "established/related" that could have the packages invisibly accepted, but i cant really find it.

Comment: I just tried your original rule on my test setup and it works perfectly. So either something doesn't match (like i said earlier) or something else is allowing packets through before the reach this statement.

Comment: Can you see the packages go through? And are you certain they still contain "disconnect" in all lowercase. And you haven't censored anything from the iptables-save?

Comment: This is what the original file exactly is and I'm just using iptables-restore to run this config. https://www.protectedtext.com/Johny ('john1234' password). I'm not sure but maybe the ESTABLISHED,RELATED rule is letting the packets through? This is because I just got a TCP ACK attack on port ranges 50000 which are supposed to be closed but instead the server replied to those packets somehow.

Comment: It shouldn't, as it is lower than your "disconnect drop" line. I can't tell why this doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering the same thing. Could you ascertain to why the closed port would work as well?

Comment: I dont follow? "The closed port"?

Comment: The closed port 52218 and others in similar range were also replying to some TCP ACK packets.

Comment: Ahh, i think i understand. Closed ports are "actively" rejecting both new connections (SYN) but also invalid stuff (like your ACK's) by replying with an RST package (reset).

Comment: Ah I see. That's it maybe then. How do I stop them from replying at all?

Comment: Haven't had to do this before, but found this several place on the web: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP

Comment: I already have this line present.

Comment: I also see the following in /var/log/messages  nf_conntrack: table full, dropping packet maybe it gets through because of this?

Comment: No i dont think so. I've never seen the error before, but the "--state NEW" is looking for stuff NOT in the table. A full table would just result in more being seen as "new" i suppose.